# How can I connect my Kubuntu 12.10 to a different pulse audio server?

Tags: 12.10, kubuntu, pulseaudio

I have configured my PC as pulseaudio server. Now I want to connect my Laptop (Kubuntu 12.10 quantal) with this pulse server.

In earlier versions there was the "padevchooser", which could be used to select a different audio sink in the network.

Comment: Relevant discussion in [LP Bug #851695](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/padevchooser/+bug/851695) from 11.10 onwards.